# Resolving component from class name with ComponentFactoryResolver in Angular 5 not working on Android OS

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova

I'm developing an Angular app which also should run on Windows and Android over Cordova.
For generating Component dynamically I'm using `ComponentFactoryResolver` like this:

```
private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver

var factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
var factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.comp);
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
```

to create a new Component. This works great on Windows but on Android doesn't. From some reason line:

```
var factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
```

returns array of nulls.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank you Chellappan, but that didn't help.

Comment: In this.resolver field _factories  is empty